# Stop vim's delayed behaviour when holding down a key

Tags: vim

Say I have a key mapped to a function. When holding down that key, vim acts as if this key is pressed many times (as it should) and calls this function that many times. This poses a problem when the function takes a while to complete. Input keys are being read faster than function calls can be made. When releasing the key, the function is still being called a number of times. I would like to stop calling the function on key release. Is this possible?

If my story was unclear, let me give an example. I'm using the plugin vimsmoothscroll. On key press 'K' it moves the cursor up 15 rows in about 0.5 seconds, giving a smooth scrolling effect. Say I hold down 'K' for 1 second. This gives the time for 2 function calls to complete. Vim reads this however as 'K' being pressed 6x (or whatever). At the time of key release, vim still executes the 4 remaining function calls, making my cursor move way to much. I always have to guess to amount of key pressing time versus cursor movement, which is rather annoying.

Any help is much appreciated!

---

**EDIT**: I wrote a very simple smooth scrolling function with a wrapper which tries to take [mMontu](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22685892/2250406)'s suggestion into account in using getchar to get rid of any remaining pending keys, but it does not seem to work. I get into a semi infinite loop in the wrapper and when pressing 'K' for more than 2 seconds I still get the undesired effect. Any vim guru advice?

```
function! ScrollUp()
    let c = 0 
    while c <= 15
        normal gk^Y          " <--- the ^Y can be produced by <Ctrl-v><Ctrl-y>
        redraw
        sleep 50m 
        let c += 1
    endwhile
endfunction

function! ScrollUpWrapper()
    let trigger = 'K' 

    call ScrollUp()
    while getchar(1) != 0
        let c = getchar(0)
        if c != trigger
            call feedkeys(c)
            break
        endif
    endwhile
endfunction

nnoremap <silent> K :call ScrollUpWrapper()<CR>
```

---

**EDIT2**: The above function had one error:

```
let trigger = 'K'
```

needed to be changed to:

```
let trigger = char2nr('K')
```

thx mMontu!

Comment: Just making sure you know about `<c-u>` and `<c-d>` for scrolling

Comment: @PeterRincker also `<c-e> and <c-y>` for "real scrolling"  :)

Comment: Yes I do know about them. Still, even with half-page up/down I would lose sight of context sometimes. This function basically does 15 times 1 row up with a short delay in between.

Comment: @Kent `<c-e>` and `<c-y>` are fine too. They are really helpful when you need some extra context doing a substitution with the confirm flag.

Comment: The <c-e> and <c-y> are really useful as well, but the question is not really about a scrolling function. That was just a function that come to mind when thinking of a function that takes quite some time to complete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `getchar()` function at the end of your function to clear any pending keys.

Then if you are still pressing the `K` it will generate more input, what will trigger the function again.

You could even check if `getchar()` is returning a `K`, and if it is not you could insert it back to the input queue using `feedkeys()`.

---

**Edit**:

The problem on your solution happens on the `if` block -- if it is removed it seems to work in the way you were looking for.

The loop is caused by the condition on the `if`. If you execute `echo getchar()` and press 'K', you get a number, not a char. This is explained in `:help getchar()`:

```
    Without {expr} and when {expr} is 0 a whole character or
    special key is returned.  If it is an 8-bit character, the
    result is a number.  Use nr2char() to convert it to a String.
    Otherwise a String is returned with the encoded character.
```

Inserting the `char2nr()` function solves the problem:

```
let trigger = char2nr('K')
```

Comment: Thank you for your idea! I tried to write a function with your suggestions, but I still have some difficulties. I will update my post shortly.